# Not able to update story's Release field, when I am dragging feature card from one release to another release column

Tags: rally

I have created a cardboard application, whiich has Backlog and releases as headers.

Each column has number of features for that release, but when I am dragging the feature, I am able to change the release field for that feature.

But not able to update that feature story's Release field.

below is my code, any suggestions, help @nickm, @kyle

```
        Ext.override(Rally.ui.cardboard.Column,{
            getStoreFilter: function(model) {
                var property = this.attribute;
                var value = this.getValue();
                if ( this.attribute == "Release" ) {
                    property = "Release.Name";
                    if ( value ) {
                        value = value.get('Name');
                    }
                }
                return {
                    property:property,
                    operator: '=',
                    value: value
                };
            },
            isMatchingRecord: function(record) {
                var recordValue = record.get(this.attribute);
                if (recordValue) {
                    recordValue = recordValue.Name;
                }
                var columnValue = this.getValue();
                if ( columnValue ) {
                    columnValue = columnValue.get('Name');
                }

                return (columnValue === recordValue );
            },
            addCard: function(card, index, highlight) {
                var record = card.getRecord();
                console.log("record what we want", record);
                var project = record.get('Context');
                var target_value = this.getValue();
                if ( target_value && typeof(target_value.get) === "function" ) {
                    target_value = this.getValue().get('_ref');         
                }
                //console.log("values to see", record, this.attribute, target_value);
                record.set(this.attribute,target_value);    
                if (target_value) {
                    this._updateStories(record, project, this.getValue()).then({
                        success: function(){
                            console.log("Updated"); 
                        },
                        scope: this
                    }, this);
                    record.set("PlannedStartDate",this.getValue().get('ReleaseStartDate'));
                    record.set("PlannedEndDate",this.getValue().get('ReleaseDate'));
                } else {    
                    record.set("PlannedStartDate",null);
                    record.set("PlannedEndDate",null);              
                }
                if (!Ext.isNumber(index)) {
                    //find where it should go
                    var records = Ext.clone(this.getRecords());
                    records.push(record);
                    this._sortRecords(records);
                    var recordIndex = 0;
                    for (var iIndex = 0, l = records.length; iIndex < l; iIndex++) {
                        var i = records[iIndex];
                        if (i.get("ObjectID") === record.get("ObjectID")) {
                            recordIndex = iIndex;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    index = recordIndex;
                }
                this._renderCard(card, index);
                if (highlight) {
                    card.highlight();
                }
                this.fireEvent('addcard');
                card.fireEvent('ready', card);
            },
            _updateStories: function(record, project, releaseVal) {
                var deferred = Ext.create('Deft.Deferred');
                Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
                    model: 'HierarchicalRequirement',
                    autoLoad: true,
                    filters: [
                        {property:'Feature.ObjectID', value: record.get('ObjectID') },
                        //{property:'Parent.ObjectID', value: record.get('ObjectID') }
                        //{property:'DirectChildrenCount',value:0 }
                    ],
                    context: project,
                    limit: Infinity,
                    fetch: ['Name','Release','ObjectID'],
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(store, stories, operation) {
                            Ext.Array.each(stories, function(story) {
                                console.log(releaseVal); // Release Object
                                story.Release = releaseVal;
                                story.save({
                                    callback: function(result, operation) {
                                        console.log("operation", operation);
                                        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) {
                                            console.log("operation", operation);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            console.log("error");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            deferred.resolve();
                        }
                    }
                }, this);   
                return deferred;                
            },
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  Or is it just not setting correctly?  My guess would be you probably have a project/release mismatch.

Comment: No error as such, just Release is not displayed for userstory..release is set correctly for feature prbm is only with userstory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're doing this:

```
story.Release = releaseVal;
```

Try this instead:

```
story.set('Release', releaseVal);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,I tried this in the start still not working

Comment: Is it possible that this story is a parent? If a story has children it cannot be scheduled for release or iteration. I have an example of bulk-creating stories and setting release here: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/bulk-create-stories-set-release that uses the syntax Kyle suggested above: record.set('Release', release.get('_ref'));

Comment: @nickm - thank you so much nick, you are awesome, yes I am able to set Release for userstories which do not have children and and the children stories too, but not able to set release for parent userstories, Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @Sontya you're welcome, by design parent stories cannot be scheduled for iteration or release, and there is no workaround for it.